# Possible equivalent definition of independence using conditional probability $P(B|A)=P(B|A^c)$

Tags: probability, independence

Prove or disprove: If $A$ and $B$ are events such that $0 < P(A) < 1$ and $P(B|A)=P(B|A^c)$ then $A$ and $B$ are independent.

I'm not really sure where to start.

Possibly useful information:

$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$

Definition of independent: $P(A)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$

Bayes theorem: $P(B|A)=\frac{P(A|B)P(B)}{P(A)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the **Law of Total Probability** we know that: $$\mathsf P(A) =\mathsf P(A\mid B)\;\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(A\mid B^c)\;\mathsf P(B^c)$$

Now, what does that reduce to when we have the following? $$\mathsf P(A\mid B)=\mathsf P(A\mid B^c)$$

Answer (score 0):

Just write out the algebra, using what you know. Note that $P(A^c\cap B) = P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. Write down $$\frac{P(A^c\cap B)}{P(A^c)}=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$$ and expand it out and ... presto ... $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.